# Fish does not run as conda base by default

Tags: 20.04, anaconda, fish, conda

I have installed Fish on my Ubuntu, but every time I open my terminal I have to run the `bash` command to initiate `conda base`. I hadn't this problem with ZSH in the past.

Is there any solution to make it run as `conda base` by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As also mentioned in [nicdelillo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58760411/3140225) in the [Add conda to path in fish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280113/add-conda-to-path-in-fish) StackOverflow question, just run the following command from your Bash shell:

```
conda init fish
```

This command will add something like this in your `.config/fish/config.fish` file:

```bsh
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
eval /home/user/miniconda3/bin/conda "shell.fish" "hook" $argv | source
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

After that just open a new fish session and you should be able to initialize your `conda` environment as you do using the Bash shell.

Comment: Okay, thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome! :D

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS, basically I made the mistake of installing anaconda before fish and it was throwing errors when launching fish shell in pycharm terminal.

- I first went to zsh shell.
- Then uninstalled anaconda using `brew uninstall anaconda`
- Then installed anaconda again `brew install anaconda`
- Finally I executed `cond init fish`

Now whenever I start a fish shell I don't get errors.